# App crashing when trying to open gallery Android pie

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, permissions, camera

I am trying to select image from gallery and code is working well on devices upto andorid nogut(7). I have added provider.xml also. This is my code

```
   public void processSelectionOfImage(int code) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

    Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    try {
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), code);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am getting NullPointerException

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: file
    at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:453)
```

Comment: What is `getOutputMediaFileUri`?

Comment: you didn't show the code where exception appears.

Comment: This question is not about nullPointerException completely. Above code is working well in devices having  Android version  7.0 but not working in above versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt method getoutputmediafileuri() in android. It is a custom method someone write for getting file URI to store captured images in particular directory. You have to defined and put logic for it. Instead of that use this code,

```
   Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyImages");
   imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
   File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
   Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
   imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
   startActivityForResult(imageIntent,0);
```